# Generics for arguments in overriden method

Tags: java, generics

Am I using generics in the wrong way?
Sorry I'm new to generics.

```
public interface Stream {
 public <T extends InputStream> void read(T in);
}

public class StreamReader implements Stream {
  @Override
 public <T extends InputStream> void read(T in) {
   ByteInputStream bis = (ByteInputStream) in;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are in search of this:

```
public interface Stream<T extends InputStream> {
    public void read(T in);
}

public class StreamReader implements Stream<ByteArrayInputStream> {

    @Override public void read(ByteArrayInputStream in) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change your method from:

```
public <T extends InputStream> void read(T in);
```

To:

```
public <T extends InputStream> void read(<T extends ByteInputStream> in);
```

Comment: that spoils the flexibility of my interface

Comment: this is not valid Java syntax